# An Arrayformula to Split the given data as shown

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

Please tell me the Arrayformula at C1 which converts the column A to column C,D & E as shown.
[image]

[Google Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zgIU9yfmURhHXZKLj8XKyIFZLuhsovvU7H2eu_S2rg8/edit?usp=sharing)

**Extra information:**
Column A is actually not raw data, it is also an Arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP($A:$A, TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY( {Sheet1!$B:$B&"^"&Sheet1!$C:$C&"^"&Sheet1!$D:$D&"#", Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A:$A&"×"}, "select max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col3",1),,9^9)), "×"), "#", CHAR(10))), 2, 0))
```

You can check the "Sheet1" & "Extra Information" sheets to understand it.

"Sheet1" Sheet:

[image]

"Extra Information" Sheet:

[image]

This Arrayformula at B1 is what I achieved, I am not able to split this by ^ into columns as shown in 1st Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in C2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE({
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({IF(Sheet1!A2:D="",,{Sheet1!A2:A&"♦", Sheet1!B2:D&"♥"}), ROW(Sheet1!A2:A)}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col5 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♦")), 2, ), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({IF(Sheet1!A2:D="",,{Sheet1!A2:A&"♦", Sheet1!B2:D&"♥"}), ROW(Sheet1!A2:A)}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col5 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♦")), 2, ), 
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({IF(Sheet1!A2:D="",,{Sheet1!A2:A&"♦", Sheet1!B2:C&"♥", TEXT(Sheet1!D2:D, "dd/mm/e")&"♥"}), ROW(Sheet1!A2:A)}, 
 "select max(Col4) where Col2 is not null group by Col5 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♦")), 2, )}, "♥$", ), "♥ ", CHAR(10))))
```

[image]

Comment: It does not work https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwe9K.png, Please Help!

Comment: @AashitGarodia answer updated

Comment: Hi, which would be more efficient using my formula individually in all 3 columns or your single formula? Is there any way I could measure or compare the efficiencies of formulas in Google Sheet?

Comment: Are you there? Please let me know^